# Hide SmartApp banner after page transition

Tags: ios, jquery-mobile

I want to show a smart banner in my JQM based web, but I want it to be shown only in the first page.
Instead it seems it has to be disabled by a direct action of the user.

I also would like to use ajax transitions, so `data-ajax=false` is not an option to resolve the question.
Do you have any hints, please?
Thank you!

Comment: What's the relation between `data-ajax="false"` and SmartApp? If you want to hide it, use `pagecontainerhide` event.

Comment: Uhm, could you be more specific, please? I thought I couldn't manipulate smartapp banner by JS. Just with a full page reload.

Comment: Honestly, I'm not sure how to manipulate smartApp banner. Since it's in `meta` tag and jQM loads `head` content of first page, the only way is to move to next page (html file) with ajax disabled and with that `meta` tag removed.

Comment: Yep, that's my issue, indeed... 
I was hoping in some magics. :D

Comment: Wait. What happens at `meta` tags in the second page? Are they loaded? Maybe they can overwrite the ones in the first page?

Comment: Only _page div_ of next page is loaded, the rest are thrown in trash. You can remove `meta` tag anytimg, but I dont know if the banner would be hidden by removing it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65352/discussion-between-omar-and-matteo).